# Powershell script to search for similar filenames

Tags: powershell, search

I am trying to build a PowerShell script that can search for files with similar names inside of a folder.

The files will always have a similar name template:

```text
filename(C).TIF
filename(M).TIF
filename(Y).TIF
filename(K).TIF
```

All I need to do is to extract the "filename", check if there are 4 similar ones (C,M,Y,K) and use it as a variable to move those files.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\test" -Filter "*.TIF" |
    Foreach-Object {$_.BaseName} | Sort-Object -Unique 

$files = $files -replace ".{3}$" 

$names = (Get-Unique -InputObject $files)  
$names
```

The result looks like this:

```text
jobname 
jobname 
jobname 
jobname 
test 
test 
test 
test
```

But I need to sort by unique and count them, maybe, before action.

Comment: That's easy enough, can you show us where you're having trouble with your code?

Comment: ```$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\test" -Filter "*.TIF" | Foreach-Object {$_.BaseName} 
    | Sort-Object -Unique
    $files = $files -replace ".{3}$"
    $names = (Get-Unique -InputObject $files)
    $names```


And this is the output:

```jobname
jobname
jobname
jobname
test
test
test
test```

My strategy was to compare or count the unique ones and trigger the action only when the count is 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I need to sort by unique and count them, maybe, before action.

You definitely want the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object)!

As the name suggests, it... *groups objects*, based on some common property:

```
$filesByCommonBaseName = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\test" -Filter "*.TIF" |Group-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '.{3}$' }
```

---

Now that you have them grouped correctly, you can start operating on them as such:

```
foreach($entry in $filesByCommonBaseName){
    Write-Host "Operating on files starting with $($entry.Name)"
    if($entry.Count -eq 4){
        # we found four matches, move them!
        $entry.Group |Move-Item -Destination $destinationDir -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Thanks a lot for the suggestion, it works to filter and group them by filename. I have not used them before. Can I interrogate every Group-object individually to check if they match the number of files?

Comment: @user3457421 Sure - `Group-Object` outputs a collection of objects with a `Name`, `Count` and `Group` property each - the `Group` property contains an array of the original items: `$filesByCommonBaseName.Where({$_.Name -eq 'test'}).Group` <- should give you all the `test*` files for example

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Awesome. That works if I am looking for a specific string, but what I need is for the script to search inside the Group-Object for the name and if there are 4 entries, move those specific files. I am sorry about the dumb questions.

Comment: @user3457421 I've updated the answer, does this make it clearer how you can do it?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen it makes perfect sense. Thank you. Can I still use a filter function inside the group-object? Like Filter "*(C).TIF" | do this...   -Filter "(M).TIF" | do something else

Comment: @user3457421 You can do whatever you want to the files - `$entry.Group |Where BaseName -like '*(C)'` - I strongly encourage you to just play around with it (that will probably be faster than asking "can I ...?" over and over) ;-)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Thank you. You are right. I am sorry. I am just learning some new cmdlets.